# How to split numbers and string into two columns using TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, devexpress

In my project, I have a column that contains numbers (including "-" symbol) and a string. I want to split it into two columns. The separator between numbers and string differs it can be " " or " - ". Is it possible to solve this issue by means of a TSQL query?
This TSQL engine is placed in Devexpress WinForms designer.

Example:

| Col: |
| --- |
| 343234-2321 String string |
| 402-09-12 - Another string |
| Just string |
| 303-404 - Text field |

Expected result

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 343234-2321 | String string |
| 402-09-12 | Another string |
| NULL | Just string |
| 303-404 | Text field |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you. Don't forget your attempts as well!

Comment: What the output you expect for `String1 string2 99283948 string3`?

Comment: @astentx there's an "expected result" table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you always need to break your string in half after the end of the numeric digits as your sample data demonstrates, a possible solution is to use `patindex`:

```
with s as (
    select col, PatIndex('%[A-z]%',col) d
    from t
)
select col,
    NullIf(Trim(case when Substring(Left(col,d-1),d-2,1)='-' then 
      Left(col,d-3)
      else Left(col,d-1) end),'') Col1,
    NullIf(Trim(NullIf(Substring(col,d,Len(col)),'')),'') Col2
from s
```

See [Example DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cef46170b373f75f19528ce495caea07)

Note, if you are using SQL2016 or prior you'll need to replace `trim` with nested `ltrim & rtrim`